# Let X be a geometric random variable with parameter p compute E[X^3]

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

Let X be a geometric random variable with parameter $p$  compute $E[X^3]$.

How would I approach this and how would I simplify the series? Can I use a moment generating function?
I am able to write out a formula for expectation, I believe it is  the sum from 1 to n of $k^3p(1-p)^{k-1}$,   I apologize for the terrible notation but I am not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: Thank you! that was very helpful!

Comment: Just enclosed it in $ signs, and the exponent in {}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write
$k^3=k(k^2-1)+k$, then
$$E[X^3]=p(1-p)\sum_{k=1}^\infty (k+1)k(k-1)\cdot (1-p)^{k-2} + p\sum_{k=1}^\infty k\cdot (1-p)^{k-1}, $$
and use the famous $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty q^n= \frac 1{1-q} $, and its derivatives.